# Why $ \vec \mu$ is induced by $\vec B_{ext}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-moment

I have read that in the presence of an external magnetic field $\vec B_{ext}$ the magnetic moment induced on a paramagnetic ion is $\vec \mu=g \mu_B \vec J$ where $g$ is the Landé g-factor.

Why is $\vec \mu$ induced by $\vec B_{ext}$? Shouldn't that magnetic moment be present even without any external magnetic field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an individual ion, you are right that an unpaired electron will lead to a permanent magnetic moment. The effect of the external field is to apply a torque such that the magnetic moment will line up with the field.

Macroscopically this is important, because without an external field, the magnetic moments of the ions are randomly oriented, and so there is no coherent, macroscopically observable field. On the other hand, when an external field is applied to a paramagnetic material, the magnetic moments for different ions will all tend to align with the external field. The collective effect of all the magnetic moments aligning can lead to an large, macroscopic magnetic field.